# how to change terrain texture in code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, renderer, terrain

I want to change the offset (2) of terrain texture through code. 
I have added a road image as a texture on the terrain.
I've found related code online, but I am unable to figure out the role of renderer in this case.

More than code, I just want to know the first step that should be taken in order to change texture through code. (Settings basically). 
And please mention the role of renderer.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Unity Terrains textures are handled by the `SplatPrototype` class. [See documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SplatPrototype.html)

> A Splat prototype is just a texture that is used by the TerrainData.

So if you want to change the *Terrain*'s *Texture* you have to create a new `SplatPrototype` and set it to the *splatPrototype* variable of `TerrainData`.

There you can set the values of `metallic`, `normalMap`, `smoothness`, `texture`,  `tileSize` and `tileOffset` of your choice.

You can use the following method:

```
private void SetTerrainSplatMap(Terrain terrain, Texture2D[] textures)
{
    var terrainData = terrain.terrainData;

    // The Splat map (Textures)
    SplatPrototype[] splatPrototype = new SplatPrototype[terrainData.splatPrototypes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < terrainData.splatPrototypes.Length; i++)
    {
        splatPrototype[i] = new SplatPrototype();
        splatPrototype[i].texture = textures[i];    //Sets the texture
        splatPrototype[i].tileSize = new Vector2(terrainData.splatPrototypes[i].tileSize.x, terrainData.splatPrototypes[i].tileSize.y);    //Sets the size of the texture
        splatPrototype[i].tileOffset = new Vector2(terrainData.splatPrototypes[i].tileOffset.x, terrainData.splatPrototypes[i].tileOffset.y);    //Sets the size of the texture
    }
    terrainData.splatPrototypes = splatPrototype;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Ill try it and let you know.

Comment: @ConnorIglesias Ok, do not forget to mark as resolved when it is done

Comment: @ConnorIglesias I think that changing the Terrain texture at runtime is an heavy operation and should be avoided in real time. Personally i use this method during the level loading.

Comment: Okay. I am actually using it for infinite run game. I'll think of any other way. Dont want to raise batches and setpasscalls.

Comment: @ConnorIglesias did you try this solution yet? Maybe it can work i never tryed in real time but i am curious to know if it does.

Comment: Thankyou so much. The code worked. It took me hours to figure out the function on splatprototype and terraindata but finally its done.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WOKED FOR ME**

```
splat[i].tileOffset = new Vector2(tar.splatPrototypes[i].tileOffset.x, tar.splatPrototypes[i].tileOffset.y+5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splat Prototypes is Deprecated. I used TerrainLayers instead to edit the tiling size of the texture.

```
    float[,,] splatMapData = terrain.terrainData.GetAlphamaps(0, 0, 100, 100);
    for (int i = 26; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            splatMapData[i, j, 0] = 0;
            splatMapData[i, j, 1] = 0;
            splatMapData[i, j, 2] = 1;
        }
    }
    TerrainLayer[] layers = terrain.terrainData.terrainLayers;
    layers[2].tileSize = new Vector2(100, 100);
    terrain.terrainData.SetAlphamaps(0, 0, splatMapData);
    terrain.Flush();
```